# Why is upgrading node version with n not working on mac?

Tags: npm, nvm, n

First I followed [this](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/update-node-js), and I managed to get the newest version installed. However, I didn't get to switch to it

```
   installed : v19.7.0 to /usr/local/bin/node
      active : v10.24.1 at /Users/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v10.24.1/bin/node
```

So I tried to do the switch with nvm, but since v19.7.0 wasn't installed under /.nvm, nvm couldn't recognize it.

```
% nvm use 19
N/A: version "19 -> N/A" is not yet installed.

You need to run "nvm install 19" to install it before using it.
```

I know it's possible to switch between versions with alias, but I don't want it to be for only one terminal window. And I don't want to download v19.7.0 again with nvm.

Why did n not work as expected and how to do the switch?

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one version of node installed. There is an active version installed by `nvm` and the version installed by `n`. The location of the version installed by `nvm` is earlier in your PATH variable which is why it is the active version.

Try uninstalling `nvm`.

You can run `n doctor` to detect and explain this problem.